# Tomcat7 doesn't start after installing Alfresco

Tags: tomcat7, alfresco

I have a problem with tomcat7.

I just install it on a Kubuntu 11.04, then i download Alfresco community 4.0.d and make all that this guide say to i need to do. http://paultiseo.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/installing-alfresco-community-4-on-ubuntu-server-12/

When i install tomcat7 it works fine, i can go to localhost:8080 and tomcat's menu appear and works fine.

But when i make following steps of the guide, and try to connect to localhtost:8080 the web doesn't load. Don't give me any error, it just keep loading and never end.

Furthemore, when i try to shutdown tomcat7, it give me an java error because something are in execution.

I'm not sure if i do somthing wrong, so i apreciate any suggestions. If you need some information just say it.

thx!

Informamtion:
**SO:** Kubuntu 11.04 32
**Tomcat:** 7
**Alfresco:** community 4.0.d

localhost.log from today:

```
    abr 15, 2013 9:21:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    abr 15, 2013 9:21:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
    abr 15, 2013 9:21:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@10da34e')
```

catalina.log from today:

```
abr 15, 2013 9:20:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:20:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:20:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:20:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:20:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:20:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
abr 15, 2013 9:20:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
abr 15, 2013 9:20:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2097 ms
abr 15, 2013 9:20:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Arrancando servicio Catalina
abr 15, 2013 9:20:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
abr 15, 2013 9:20:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Despliegue del archivo /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/share.war de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:21:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Despliegue del directorio /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/host-manager de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:21:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Despliegue del directorio /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/docs de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:21:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Despliegue del directorio /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/examples de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:21:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Despliegue del directorio /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/manager de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:21:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Despliegue del directorio /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:21:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Despliegue del directorio /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/alfresco de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:21:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: El escuchador "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" ya estÃ¡ configurado para este contexto. La definiciÃ³n duplicada ha sido ignorada.
abr 15, 2013 9:31:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:31:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:31:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:31:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:31:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Se encuentra instalada una versiÃ³n incompatible 1.1.20 de la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat, mientras que Tomcat necesita la versiÃ³n 1.1.24
abr 15, 2013 9:31:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
abr 15, 2013 9:31:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
abr 15, 2013 9:31:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1489 ms
abr 15, 2013 9:31:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Arrancando servicio Catalina
abr 15, 2013 9:31:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
abr 15, 2013 9:31:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Despliegue del archivo /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/share.war de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:31:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Despliegue del archivo /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/alfresco.war de la aplicaciÃ³n web
abr 15, 2013 9:31:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: El escuchador "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" ya estÃ¡ configurado para este contexto. La definiciÃ³n duplicada ha sido ignorada.
abr 15, 2013 9:32:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.StackTraceElement.equals(StackTraceElement.java:204)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:688)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:666)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:720)
    at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:157)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.publish(FileHandler.java:200)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:565)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:586)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:786)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:185)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:768)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1402)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What's in your alfresco.log file?

Comment: You should include the errors in the question. It will help people understand the problem better.

Comment: I edit with the alfresco.log, i can't include the errors because it donesn't give me errors, thats the big problem...

Comment: Alfresco cant find the required Postgresql JDB driver - this should be something like postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4.jar in tomcat/lib

Comment: I have that .jar at tomcat/shared/lib not at tomcat/lib, what i should do? Move it into tomcat/lib or change some conf to say it that search it into tomacat/shared/lib?

Comment: I'd suggest removing it from any of the tomcat lib folders, and rely on the one that ships as part of the alfresco war.

Comment: I move it from /shared/lib to /lib and doesn't work. ¡I remove it frome all the lib folders and doesn't work. alfresco.log doesn't say nothing more, but i find another logs, edit it at question info.

Comment: IIRR, shared/lib and shared/classes is by default not used in recent tomcat versions. For Alfresco to run on a plain Tomcat you need this anyway, as Alfresco suggests to put config files in shared/classes. So check if your catalina.properties has the following line uncommented: "shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/classes,${catalina.base}/shared/lib/*.jar"

Comment: Cheer up, a different error message means progress! Maybe this blog helps you fix your memory problem: http://deepak-keswani.blogspot.de/2011/09/how-to-fix-tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryer.html

Comment: I have this line at catalina.propieties: shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared/classes,${catalina.home}/shared/*.jar,/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes,/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/lib/*.jar

Comment: And the other link, i check it, but my .sh don't look like the .bat example. So i don't know where i should put that line. But in the guide i'm using for alfresco instalation, says that i should edit catalina.propieties to add this lines:
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms128m - So i edit the line that looks like that ones in your link, and let it like:
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms256m - AND NOW TOMCAT WORKS AT localhost:8080, but localhost:8080/alfresco still doesn't working, localhost:8080/share works, but i cant login with alfresco/alfresco

Comment: "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space": how much memory are you giving to tomcat? Alfresco would want at least a gigabyte of memory, but two would do much better. And the thing to help performance best is to move away the db to another machine.

Comment: I increment the memory for tomcat (or i think i do it). I put this lines on catalina.propieties: JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_17
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms256m -Dalfresco.home=/opt/alfresco -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode"

Comment: Now the aplication /alfresco doesn't start. It give me an error if i try to run it. And when i start tomcat the log says that: `SEVERE: The web application ³ n [/ alfresco] created a ThreadLocal with key ³ the type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory $ 1] (value [$ 1 @ 166a9c2 com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class = java.lang.ref.WeakReference @ 1133390 javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler}]) but failed to remove it when the web application stops ³ n ³. The wires are to renew with time in an attempt to avoid possible memory failure.`

Answer (score 0):

Please restart your PC and try it again.

Comment: I restart it so many times, i have that problem since onae week ago. I try to restart, reinstall all, drop and remake the dbs, and i search all that i can in google, but nobody know the solution.

Comment: It's not Windows, restarting the computer is almost never the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak your JAVA_OPTS and allow more memory for the JVM PermGen. For Alfresco 4.x a general good value would be 256m.

The article you are referencing instructs to use JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms128m -Dalfresco.home=/opt/alfresco -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", which is -- depending on your available memory and Xmx settings -- too much.

If you followed the instructions, the JAVA_OPTS variable is not set properly/overwritten elsewhere. You can see the arguments passed to tomcat with 'ps aux | grep java' or something alike.

Alfresco wiki reference (not updated since Alfresco 3.4 I think, but this information is still relevant): http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JVM_Tuning#Permanent_Generation_.28PermGen.29_Size